# How to model {smallmatrix} with {array}?

Tags: matrices, arrays

It is pretty normal, I guess, to use `\begin{array} ... \end{array}` to model matrices, when more control is required than you get with `pmatrix`, `bmatrix`, etc., with the proper `\left` and `\right`, and the relevant symbol.

Now, I need `smallmatrix`, but I need more control. Basically, I'd like to model `\begin{smallmatrix} ... \end{smallmatrix}` with `\begin{array} ... \end{array}`.

It's not as easy as just putting a command left and right of `\begin{array} ... \end{array}`. Should I use `\scalebox`?

```
\begin{array}{c|c}
    a & b \\ \hline c & d
\end{array}
```

As you can see, I'm using verical and horizonal lines. Now I'd need that, but in this matrix:

```
\begin{smallmatrix}
    a & b \\ \hline c & d
\end{smallmatrix}
```

Is that even possible?

Comment: `smallmatrix` is optimized for two line arrays so that the delimiters around them don't grow too much; as soon as you add a horizontal rule the size will grow. A partitioned matrix is best treated in a display.

Comment: I understand, but even adding vertical lines is not possible. I'd like to control at least that.

Answer (score 7):

You can emulate `smallmatrix` with `array` in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % just for comparison

\newenvironment{smallarray}[1]
 {\null\,\vcenter\bgroup\scriptsize
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.7}%
  \arraycolsep=.13885em
  \hbox\bgroup$\array{@{}#1@{}}}
 {\endarray$\egroup\egroup\,\null}

\begin{document}
$\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a & b\\ g&d\end{smallmatrix}\right]
\left[\begin{smallarray}{cc}a & b\\g&d\end{smallarray}\right]
\left[\begin{smallarray}{c|c}a & b\\g&d\end{smallarray}\right]$
\end{document}
```

However, adding `\hline` between rows in a `smallarray` won't give a pleasant result.

Horizontal rules may be added in both environments with

```
\noalign{\vskip1pt\hrule\vskip1pt}
```

instead of `\hline`, but this will probably make delimiters grow by one step.

[image]